# Please help me evaluate this messy limit

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function

I'd like to solve a limit of this form: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\Big[\log\Big( \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p) - p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p)}  \Big)\Big] $$
But I'm not sure how to start? Does anyone have any idea - can we use L'Hopital's rule here?

Comment: Your title says nothing about the content of your question. The tag limsup-and-liminf does not apply. The exponential term vanishes in the limit leaving you with, well, nothing.

Comment: Sorry the limsup liminf tag was a mistake, I'll delete it..

Answer (score 1):

It's not an indeterminate form so we don't have to use anything other than basic limit laws. Also, we assume $x\ne p$ and $p(p-1)\ne 0$ for the divisions to be defined.
$$\log\left( \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p) - p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p)}  \right)=\log\left(1-\frac{p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p)}\right) $$
Notice that
$$e^{-\frac{n}{2}\left(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)}\right)^2}\to 0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p)}\to 0\,\,(n\to\infty) $$
so the logarithm approaches $\log(1)=0$. And $\frac 1n\to 0$. Therefore, the limit is $0$.

Comment: Please notice that Bjorn93's answer avoids circular reasoning by not using the $\lim$ notation *before* the existence of the relevant limit has been established. In fact, the $\lim$ notation is not used at all. Depending on the intended audience, I would stress that we actively use the continuity of the logarithm.

Comment: @CarlChristian yes, the argument of the logarithm approaches $1$. By the continuity of the log function, the logarithm approaches $\log(1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\Big[\log\Big( \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p) - p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p)}  \Big)\Big] $$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\Big[\log\Big(1- \frac{ p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p)}  \Big)\Big] $$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\Big[- \frac{ p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (x-p)}  +O(\frac{e^{-n(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2}}{n})\Big] $$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} - \frac{ p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi n^3} (x-p)}  +O(\frac{e^{-n(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2}}{n^2})
$$
$$=-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  p(1-p) e^{-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{x-p}{p(1-p)})^2} \cdot
 \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{ 1}{\sqrt{2\pi n^3} (x-p)} =0
$$